# how create afterAction for every method of controller in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

is afterAction works for every action of controller in yii2????

if not how we should make afteraction for every method of controller???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `afterAction()` event handler triggers for every action in controller.

Take a look at the [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#afterAction%28%29-detail) for this method:

> This method is invoked right after an action is executed.
>
> The method will trigger the `EVENT_AFTER_ACTION event`. The return
>   value of the method will be used as the action return value.
>
> If you override this method, your code should look like the following:

```
public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);
    // your custom code here
    return $result;
}
```

If you need limit execution of some code for specific actions, you can use `$action` variable like this:

For single action:

```
if ($action->id == '...') {
    ...
}
```

For multiple actions:

```
if (in_array($action->id, [..., ...]) {
    ...
}
```

Or you can use `$action->uniqueId` instead.